# How can I predict the asymptotic behavior of a function (not its numerical limit) by simplifying it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a complicated function which I intend to predict its asymptotic behavior (specially I have a $f(r)$ which I want to know its asymptotic behavior in $r\rightarrow \infty$). I know that the command `Limit` gives me the numerical limit of the function in the special limits instead, I need a function which simulate the behavior of the original function in the limits in the best possible way. Let me get help from a toy example:
We know the limit of `Sin[x]` for `x->0` is 0 namely

```
Limit[Sin[x], x -> 0]
 (*0*)
```

but we know it behaves just as `x` function in small `x`s. The following plot shows this fact:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

So we say `x` function simulates the asymptotic behavior of `Sin[x]`. I need to find such a thing for my complicated function. Note that I don't want use fitting or something else, I just want to reach such a function by manipulating (for example choosing terms whit high growth rate and removing other terms) my original function (what was not possible for simple `Sin[x]` function). Is there any command in Mathematica to do this?

**Addendum**

This is the closed form of my function:

```
f[re_] := 
  1/(8 Sqrt[2]
     mp re \[Gamma] (M^2 \[Beta] + mp^2 \[Gamma]) Sqrt[\[Beta] + (
     mp^2 \[Gamma])/M^2]) E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma]) M^2 norm^2 \[Pi]^(
   3/2) (E^((M \[Alpha] - 2 mp re \[Gamma])^2/(
      2 (M^2 \[Beta] + 
         mp^2 \[Gamma]))) ((-1 + E^((4 M mp re \[Alpha] \[Gamma])/(
           M^2 \[Beta] + mp^2 \[Gamma]))) M \[Alpha] + 
        2 (1 + E^((4 M mp re \[Alpha] \[Gamma])/(
           M^2 \[Beta] + mp^2 \[Gamma]))) mp re \[Gamma]) + 
     E^((M \[Alpha] - 2 mp re \[Gamma])^2/(
      2 (M^2 \[Beta] + mp^2 \[Gamma]))) (M \[Alpha] - 
        2 mp re \[Gamma]) Erf[(M \[Alpha] - 2 mp re \[Gamma])/(
       Sqrt[2] M Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp^2 \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
     E^((M \[Alpha] + 2 mp re \[Gamma])^2/(
      2 (M^2 \[Beta] + mp^2 \[Gamma]))) (M \[Alpha] + 
        2 mp re \[Gamma]) Erf[(M \[Alpha] + 2 mp re \[Gamma])/(
       Sqrt[2] M Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp^2 \[Gamma])/M^2])]);
```

where all parameters are real and positive. I want to find asymptotic behavior of `f[re]` when `re` goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes, there is. It is called [`Asymptotic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html). Use it as ``Asymptotic[f, r -> Infinity]``.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot, However it returns 0 for me!

Comment: With v13.0.1, `Asymptotic[Sin[x], x -> 0]` evaluates to `x`; `Asymptotic[Sin[x], x -> 0, SeriesTermGoal -> 3]` evaluates to  `x - x^3/6` and `Asymptotic[Sin[x], x -> Infinity]` evaluates to `Sin[x]`

Comment: @Wisdom, it is hard to comment without you giving us the definition of your function ...

Comment: Before `Asymptotic` we used `Series`

Comment: @Domen Please see the addendum.

Comment: @Wisdom with the function you provided in the OP the command `f[x] // Series[#, {x, Infinity, 1}] & // Normal // Factor` returns [`this result`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzuC4.png). [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) took a bit too long for me to wait

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes as I said

Comment: With `srs = Series[f[x], {x, Infinity, 1}] // Normal;` we take into account the positivity and the command `Assuming[α > 0 && β > 0 && γ > 0 && M > 0 && 
  mp > 0, FullSimplify[srs]]` returns [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEZMC.png)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't get why you are sorry. And to whom your apologizing

Comment: @bmf Apologizing to Wisdom for not reading the question carefully.  Anyway, I think they've seen it, so I'll delete it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
FullSimplify[
 Series[f[re], {re, Infinity, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> 
   Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0]], 
 Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0]]

FullSimplify[Normal[%], 
 Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0]]
(*
-((E^((M (M α^2 - 
     4 re (mp α + M re β) γ))/(
  2 (M^2 β + mp^2 γ))) M^3 norm^2 π^(
  3/2) (M α - 2 mp re γ))/(
 4 Sqrt[2] mp re γ (M^2 β + mp^2 γ)^(3/2)))
*)
```

Or, to remove an extra term:

```
FullSimplify[Normal@Series[%, {re, Infinity, 0}], 
 Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0]]
(*
(E^((M (M α^2 - 4 re (mp α + M re β) γ))/(
 2 (M^2 β + mp^2 γ))) M^3 norm^2 π^(
 3/2))/(2 Sqrt[2] (M^2 β + mp^2 γ)^(3/2))
*)
```

Or to get the same thing:

```
FullSimplify[
 Asymptotic[f[re], re -> Infinity, 
  Assumptions -> 
   Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0], 
  SeriesTermGoal -> 1], 
 Thread[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α} > 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the answer for your first code but the second returns a different answer, why? And I will be so grateful if you add some explanation about your first code using `Series`, how does it work?

Comment: @Wisdom The first code produces an extra term. Sometimes, esp. when there are factors without a series expansion, you have to go past the desired number of terms in order to get desired term.  You can then apply `Series` to trim the series.  `Series` works like `Asymptotic`. If you ask for `Normal@Series[f[re], {re, Infinity, 0}]` and simplify, you get `0` just like with your first try at `Asymptotic`.

Comment: The Asymptotic version can be simplified a bit with: `Assuming[
 Element[{γ, M, mp, norm, β, α}, PositiveReals],
 FullSimplify @ Asymptotic[f[re], re -> Infinity]
 ]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry for delay and Thanks a lot for your answer.